# constraint validation invalid django

Tags: python-3.x, django, unique-constraint

I am trying to validate a form but it goes to the database and return the constraint validation error.

form.py

```
from django import forms
from . models import Semana

class FormularioSemana(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Semana
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {'lunes_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'lunes_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'martes_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'martes_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'miercoles_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'miercoles_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'jueves_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'jueves_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'viernes_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'viernes_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'sabado_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'sabado_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'domingo_inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        'domingo_fin': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        }
        def __init__(self, username, *args, **kwargs):
            super(FormularioSemana, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Set the instance's solicitante to the passed user. With this, you no longer have to do it in your views.py as well
            self.instance.username = username
            if not username.is_staff: # note that I moved the queryset filtering inside the if statement to avoid logical errors when user.is_staff is True
                self.fields['nombre'].queryset = nombre.stem.filter(username = request.user)

        def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
                # Get the values
            nombre = self.cleaned_data['nombre']
            username = self.instance.username

        # Find the duplicates
            duplicates = Semana.stem.filter(
                nombre=nombre,
                username=username
                )
            if self.instance.pk:
                duplicates = duplicates.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
            if duplicates.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('El nombre de la semana existe!')
```

I think the problem is here but i dont see them

views.py

```
    def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormularioSemana(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            add_usuario = form.save(commit=False)
            add_usuario.username = request.user
            add_usuario.save()
            all_items = semanaDb.stem.filter(username = request.user)
            semana = FormularioSemana()
            messages.success(request, ('New item added...'))
            #item = semanaDb.objects.filter(id=id)
            #item.delete()
        return render (request, 'semana.html', {'form':semana, 'all_items':all_items})

    else:
        semana = FormularioSemana()
        all_items = semanaDb.stem.filter(username = request.user)
        
        #item = semanaDb.objects.filter(id=id)
        #item.delete()
        return render(request, 'semana.html', {'form':semana, 'all_items':all_items})
```

models contraint --->

```
    class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['username', 'nombre'], name='nombre unico')
    ]
```

It runs but the forms no validate the constraint.
More info. I have used in form **all**, and fields too.

Comment: Your form does not contain the username field so it is excluded from any constraint validation

Comment: it give me an error i change it to fields = '__all__'

 File "/home/dani/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: taskManager_semana.username_id, taskManager_semana.nombre